# rack-offline Gem:How to exclude certain files from caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cache-manifest, html5-appcache

I am using the gem rack offline(  https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline) in my rails app for offline caching.

Due to some reason I need make sure that certain HTML files are never cached offline and is always loaded from server.I know,this is bad.But My app was not designed to work offline and now forced to make a part(client demand!),specifically just 3 pages,work offline.So I need to make sure that only those 3 pages are cached..and no other HTML files are cached.

How do I accomplish this?

PS:I have gone through the Github pages for the gem and I guess I can accomplish this by manipulating the "network" property.But not able to find how..